# Is there a way to change sound profiles based on GPS position?

Tags: gps, profiles

I thought heard about an app that could change sound profiles based on GPS position, but I forgot which one it was. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The free app [android llama](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kebab.Llama&hl=en) can do this.

Best of all it is not required to use the energy-expensive gps-receiver but can do the same also with "wlan-ids-in-reach" and "cell-phone-masts-in-reach" as alternative.

Answer (score 2):

You can try apps like [tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=en) and [locale](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.twofortyfouram.locale&hl=en)for this. They are paid app though.

Answer (score 1):

You can try my app [HomeProfile](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.homeprofile), too. It changes your sound profile when your device connects with a specific WiFi or when it is disconnected from it.